# VBA Word convert formatted text into track changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to revert back a document that has false track changes into real track changes.

I have written this code, but it slows down a lot the application and Word hangs up. Is there a better alternative?

```
Sub FormattingToTC()
    'Main procedure for the transformation of track changes
    Dim rev As Revision
    Dim sect As Section
    Dim selAccepted As Selection
    Dim selDel As Selection
    Dim storyRange As Range
    Dim strFullName As String, strName As String, strOldFullName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim OriginalDoc As Document

    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    ActiveDocument.TrackFormatting = False
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False


    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.StrikeThrough = True  'Find all strikethrough text
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True  'All matches are deleted with tracked changes active
        ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
        Selection.Delete
    Loop
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True  'Find all hihglighted text
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True

    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True  'All matches are deleted with tracked changes active
        ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
        Selection.paste
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
end sub
```

It would be only for the part of deletions. Is another way to do that avoiding that loops? For example with find and replace?

Comment: If your code works, it's probably better to ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What do you mean by "Word hangs up"? Describe that exactly, please. Two things you could try: 1) Use a RANGE instead of the Selection object; 2) Test (as a user, to see if it works the way you want) using REPLACE and leave the Replace box empty. That should replace the found term with nothing (delete it)...